# Two layers referencing same dataset not behaving as expected in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfield-cloud

In QGIS I have a single layer in a GeoPackage (.gpkg) file but symbolized in two different ways in separate layers. In QGIS if I add a feature to it, the new feature is visible in both versions of the same layer.  In QField it appears that the new version has been separated in to two layers because when a feature is added to one of the layers the change only appears on that version.  Is there a way to resolve this?  I have tested it on QFieldCloud and QFieldSync with the same results.

Comment: How did you setup your project for QField, ? Are you sure two separate layer weren't created along the process, if yes you should be able to edit the project to revert to using the same data for both layer

Comment: I agree with J.R., have a look at whether the data source of the relevant layers in the Qfield project is the same. Unfortunately packaging using the QField app can create whole new layers for ones that were originally duplicated

Comment: Thanks both - The project for QField was created using "Convert Currently Open Project to Cloud Project" option.  It seems to have uploaded just the one gpkg and I cannot see an additional dataset it has created, when the gpkg is downloaded and checked in QGIS. However if I edit one in QField the change only appears on one of the the layers in QField.

Comment: Why not create two seperate symbols on the onew layer - you can switch them on and off in QGIS and QField, and even use themes to make this easier - this will avoid the issue.

Comment: Thanks Oisin - that sounds ideal. How would i turn of the symbol of a single layer in QField though?  Would that be using a Map Theme?

Answer (score 0):

Create two seperate symbols on the one layer - you can switch them on and off in QGIS and QField.

To swith symbologies on or off in Qfield,

1. Open the menu (button with three horizonal lines at top left)
2. If required, expand group to see relevant layer.
3. Long press layer to expand and see different symbologies
4. Long press symbology item, and toggle on or off as required.

You can also create you map themes with different layers or their different symbologies turned on or off etc. If you create themes, a drop down with all themes appears above the layers in QField's menu.